# Jqgrid missing documentation on assembly version

Tags: jqgrid

I am planning to buy a commercial license of jqgrid to get the possibility to use Jqgrid as an assembly on my aspx site, but I am struggeling to find any documentation on the library..

Every bit of documentation I find is showing example of javascripts, but I need documentation on the use of the asp component..

Anyone know where I can find this? I thought that the commercial license would have better documentation..

**EDIT**

I dont know how I didn't find this site, but the demo site is very good!

http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnet.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the API documentation for the jqGrid ASP.NET components: http://www.trirand.net/documentation.aspx

The same page has links to demos and other useful information for the components. Also keep in mind that these components still render a JavaScript grid on the web page, so some of the JavaScript documentation may still be applicable depending upon your needs.